# How to align the elements of a ruby method call on Vim

Tags: ruby, vim, indentation

According to the [ruby-style-guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#user-content-no-double-indent), this is the preferable way to align the elements of a method call:

```
method :arg1,
       :arg2,
       :arg3
```

However, this is what I got when I try to indent the whole file using `gg=G`:

```
method :arg1,
  :arg2,
  :arg3
```

I'm currently using [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) and [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) plugins.

Is it possible to get vim indentation to work like the style guide suggests?

Comment: I think you mean when calling a method passing options hash for this style?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

These plugins should work as expected.  However, you should not need to line break arguments passed to a method.  You define them like this.

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  #do stuff
end
```

Or you can omit the parens in the method definition:

```
def my_method arg1, ar2, arg3
  #do stuff
end
```

For a method which takes an options hash:

```
def my_method(opt={})
  #do stuff
end
```

And to call the above you can do

```
my_method(foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar')
```

But if you typed this, `gg=G` should fix it correctly:

```
my_method(
foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bary
    )
```

Using `gg=G` should change it to:

```
my_method(
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
)
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time. You're right. It does work with parentheses. But the problem that I'm having is with methods that are part of Rails internal DSL, like `validates`.

Comment: I like to omit the parentheses in these cases.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way then. The style guide does not recommend omitting parens when passing options hash args. Perhaps your issue is one of the reasons.  https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-braces-options-hash

Comment: But perhaps post a better example in your question?  Otherwise, I would recommend using the parens especially when passing options hash argument as a multi-line style.